# Как заблокировать строку в таблице?

Tags: sql-server, sql

Создаю запросы  при помощи Microsoft SQL Server 2008. Есть справочник, в котором нужно заблокировать отдельные строки, чтобы нельзя было их использовать в новых запросах, но они работали в ранее созданных. Как это сделать средствами Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: Sql Server не может определить, где запрос, созданный раньше, а где позже.

Comment: Тут вопрос не в запросах, а в строках в таблице. Есть строки, которые на сегодняшний день стали не актуальны и их не надо использовать сейчас и далее. Но в старых отчетах они фигурируют и без их использования отчеты не будут работать правильно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать одно представление (`view`), которое будет делать запрос на все записи таблицы, кроме отдельных, которые быть не должны. И в программе надо делать запросы уже не к таблице с ненужными строками, а к представлению. Тем более, что при добавлении новых строк, представление будет выводить и их. Так что это, по-моему, довольно безопасно.